# How can I copy/paste data to and from the Windows clipboard to an OpenSuse clipboard using VNC?

Tags: opensuse, vnc, clipboard, copy-paste

I am connecting to a remote OpenSuse computer using VNC from Windows. On other Linuces that I've used over VNC, I can copy text between the remote machine and the local Windows machine using the clipboard. In this case, I can seem to connect the local clipboard to the remote.

The VNC server is whatever is set by default on OpenSuse. I don't know which it is.

How can I fix copy/paste over VNC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved this by installing the `autocutsel` RPM from the software management section of Yast, and then running:

```
$ autocutsel -s PRIMARY -fork
```

This enabled copy/paste between my VNC and my Windows clipboard.

Thanks to [this source](http://thomas.patrickdepinguin.com/knowledgebase/tight-vnc).

Answer (score 9):

Yes,  I just went thru this again on CentOS 5.2 (setting up old dev environment).
Add this to  `$HOME/.vnc/xstartup` worked for KDE and GNOME and ICEWM to enable copy/paste between VNC Client on Windows and the Windows host:

```
vncconfig  -nowin &
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
autocutsel -fork
```

Answer (score 7):

Copy/paste to work add these:

1. `sudo apt-get install autocutsel`
2. add `autocutsel -fork` line to `xstartup file` with:

   ```
   vi /home/<username>/.vnc/xstartup
   ```

   like this:

   ```
    #!/bin/bash  
    xrdb $HOME/.Xresources  
    autocutsel -fork  
    startxfce4 &
   ```
3. restart vncserver

Comment: Could you please expand about the need for `xrdb $HOME/.Xresources` in this case?

Comment: `xrdb $HOME/.Xresources`
it worked for me, i found it in some google pages, and i consolidated it here

Comment: This is correct and the proper way to do copy/paste between machines through VNC.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, `vncserver` executable itself does not provide clipboard support. You should run `vncconfig`, then you have clipboard support.

How you should run `vncconfig` depends on the way you use vnc server. If you are starting the server from desktop you can run the executable while starting the server. If you are starting the server at boot time, you can start the `vncconfig`  in headless mode too. I believe it is possible to run `vncconfig` in headless mode with `-nowin` flag.

You can refer to [man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/vncconfig) page of `vncconfig` for more info.

Comment: I don't seem to have any vncconfig installed.  What should I make of that?

Comment: I'm not an OpenSUSE user but after a Google search It came out they use tightvnc and vncconfig is missing in the OpenSUSE package. Without vncconfig it is not possible to use clipboard integration through vnc clients. 

You can try to install Real VNC Server or any other vnc server clone that supports clipboard integration through vncconfig or by any other mean.

Comment: This method also works if the vnc module (Tiger VNC) is loaded into a normal Xorg server (i.e. to support remote and local access to a real display).

Answer (score 0):

For over a year I have been using tightVNC from a Windows client to a RHEL server. Copy-and-paste worked well until a few weeks ago. Then it stopped. I found that the vnc service was "defunct" (not sure what that meant, but it did not sound good).

```
ps -u myUserid | grep vnc
 3414 ?        00:00:01 Xvnc
 3450 ?        00:00:00 vncconfig
 6227 pts/0    20:15:56 Xvnc
 6235 pts/0    00:00:12 vncconfig <defunct>
```

So I restarted it in the background, from a terminal in my Windows session:

```
vncconfig &
```

Now everything is back to normal. In fact the above command/response lines were copied from Linux and pasted into my Windows browser session.
No need for autocutsel.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to your VM machine.
Open your terminal and write:

> vncconfig -display :1

NOTE: Please give the spaces as given above in the command.

A pop-up will appear. **Don't close it.**
Now, copy-paste will work from VM to Windows and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

On the right corner of the Linux, the scissor is located. right-click and close the default clipboard manager and then start with Tigervnc clipboard manager as :

```
$ vncconfig &
```

It will start the TigerVNC clipboard. So you can share the clipboard with the local and remote machine.

I have tested and worked this on Oracle Linux.